# Page--front.tpl.php not working - Tao theme

Tags: 7, theming

This should be really simple, maybe I'm just having a moment. Why is my page--front.tpl.php not rendering my home page? I'm using a tao subtheme.

Here's my tpl.php file.

[image]

(*There's no other page--front.tpl.php in the tao folder.*)

Here's my front page settings:

[image]

And here's theme developer telling me that the front page is using page.tpl.php to load:

[image]

I've cleared my cache with drush a couple times and restarted my local server. What else am I missing?

Comment: are the user/group ids and permissions the same as the rest of the files in the directory?  eg, can your webserver read it.

Comment: don't add .php at the last of file name, just only add the page--front.tpl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see a Windows specific issue here.

Notice how `block.tpl` only has the extension `tpl` and your new file `page--front.tpl.php` has `php` as extension in the filename?

Maybe Windows hides the `php` extension when you list files (and instead shows it under Type)?

Try removing `.php` from `page--front.tpl.php` and see if it still under the Type column shows up as php. If so clear cache and carry on :)

Comment: Spot on :D Thank you so much for that, it actually solved another problem where I'd done the same thing as well. (Also thank you to Bala for spotting the same thing)

Answer (score 1):

Following steps resolved the issue to create custom front page for Drupal 7.

1. Create a file - page--front.tpl.php. Notice two hyphens instead of
   one.
2. Clear the cache - Configuration >> Development >> Performance>>
   Clear all caches